# Show a modal dialog while running a long UI operation on Main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I want to display a modal dialog with a progress bar while doing some work on the main UI Thread. Without using any multi-threading technique my UI would for sure be in a hanging state.

How do I achieve this while running the computationally intensive long operation on the main thread (as it involves UI elements and I shudder to touch this legacy code), while displaying the status of the computation on the wait window (which shall run on a different thread)

I need to run a progress dialog window on a different thread while keeping the main thread occupied to compute the long bound operation involving main UI form elements.

Thanks for some pointers

Comment: You don't run cpu bound operations on the main thread. You run them on a BackgroundWorker. Also, the modal dialog (wait window) usually runs on the main (UI) thread because it is generally created by statements executed in the main (UI) thread. Therefore, start a backgroundworker, attach to DoWork event and implement your long running task in the event handler. Right after starting it, you can show the modal window.

Comment: You should make your progress/wait window _modeless_ too in case you want to add a **Cancel** button.  Think Windows File Copy windows in Explorer.  Then you can just cancel the `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: If you can you .NET 4.5+ there are nice patterns using ```async``` and ```await``` together with ```Task.Run``` which will make this easier. As others have noted you need to do the work on a background thread to keep the UI from frosting over, but you don't need to resort to background worker.

Comment: Also, take a look at the [```System.Progress<T>```](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) type.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your suggestions. I shall try it to implement it and get back

Answer (score 1):

UI can not be run in different thread. It should run in UIThread. You'll have to rewrite intense operations in different thread and pass parameters to it using dispatcher (since UI elements are accessible from UI Thread as I mentioned). If you block main thread you won't be able to show progress.

Comment: Exactly that's my concern. The long running operation has interact with the UI elements. And I'm not able to block them to show Wait window

Comment: As far as I remember Background worker can access UI controls. The problem is that you progress won't be showing progress since intense operations blocks the main thread not with blocked ui elements.

Comment: Yes via `ReportProgress()`. You can update the UI in the event handler of `ProgressChanged`

Comment: @this-Me Unless your calculation can be run iteratively, progress may not be possible.

Comment: The thing is even the Wait window has to process the progress bar UI element and the main window running in the background has to process the corresponding UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is updating status(progress bar) to the user while running that long task, then the solution is In Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false

community advice's not to set that property to false, but i love to access all controls from any thread and it works fine and it's strait-forward, unless someone gives us a good reason not to use it other than "it's bad use Invoke instead".

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //To avoid  Cross-thread exception
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        //Start background task
        bkg.RunWorkerAsync();
        //show wait form 
        var frmWait = new WaitForm();
        frmWait.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void bkg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        //Do your work and update status
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its technically possible to create a Model Dialog on a thread other than UI thread (but **certainly not advisable**)

Anyway, since you cant change the legacy code, and want the model dialog to work on another thread, here is a suggestion

1> Create & open the Model dialog on separate thread

2> The Computation intensive work must be firing some event that would hook to report progress. These events are being fired from UI thread and you have to marshal them to the thread which created this model dialog. use `Control.InvokeRequired` to detect that the call stack is from another thread & use `control.Invoke(action)`to marshal it